# Redis doesn't rewrite appendonly file automatically

Tags: redis, persistence

Redis doesn't rewrite the appendonly file automatically.

My dump.rdb is 3Gb, but the appendonly file is 36Gb and filled up the disk.

Related configuration:

```
appendonly yes
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appendfsync no
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite yes
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
```

As I understood this line should make redis to rewrite aof when size has grown 100%.

```
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
```

Does it make a new aof in the background and compares with the current size? 
I did rewrite manually and aof is ~4GB, then why it didn't rewrite it?

EDIT:

Redis version: 2.8.4

Comment: What Redis version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I get these informations:

1. You open the RDB and AOF at the same time.
2. Manual rewrite command success.
3. `auto-aof-rewrite-percentage` config ok.
4. Automatic rewrite never triggered.

AOF will delay when RDB is running. I guess, the Redis was busy with `RDB bgsave`, and `AOF rewrite` delayed for each check util disk full. The `AOF rewrite` checking frequency is base on the configration `hz`.

Check the INFO command for rdb and aof information to assure that.